# Number of elements of order 4 in $\mathbb{R/Z}$ under addition - Fraleigh p. 152 Theorem 15.19(e

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

> True or False. $\mathbb{R/Z}$ under addition has an infinite number of elements of order 4.
>
> **Answer:** http://www.auburn.edu/~huanghu/math5310/alg-hw-ans-`i think 3`.pdf
>   False. $\mathbb{R/Z}$ only has two elements of order 4, i.e. 0.25$+ \mathbb{Z}$ and 0.75$+ \mathbb{Z}$.

(1.) How do you calculate there are only two elements of order 4?
(2.) How do you calculate what they are?

I know $\mathbb{R/Z} := \{r + \mathbb{Z} : r \in \color{brown}{\mathbb{R}} \}$. Because $<\mathbb{Z}> = \mathbb{Z}$, hence I think I can rewrite as:
$\mathbb{R/Z} := \{ \; r + \mathbb{Z} : r \in \color{brown}{[0,1)} \; \}$. Now I want to find $x$ such that $x + \mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z}$? How to sally forth?

I tried http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=291248 but it frets about primes?
http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091013085148AAIRD94 looks too much.

Answer (score 2):

Well for $a+\mathbb Z$ to have order $4$, we first of all need that $$(a+\mathbb Z)+(a+\mathbb Z)+(a+\mathbb Z)+(a+\mathbb Z)=0+\mathbb Z$$
i.e. $4a\in \mathbb Z$. Since we can always (uniquely) arrange for $0\le a<1$, this leaves us with $4a\in\{0,1,2,3\}$, i.e.  $a=\frac04=0$, $a=\frac14$, $a=\frac24=\frac12$, or $a=\frac34$. Of these, only $\frac14$ and $\frac34$ do indeed lead to order $4$, the others have order $1$ and $2$, respectively. (More generally, $\frac xy+\mathbb Z$ where $x\in\mathbb Z$, $y\in\mathbb N$ and $\gcd(x,y)=1$ has order $y$ in $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$; and $r+\mathbb Z$ with irrational $r$ has infinite order)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Upvoted. Can you please just clarify what you mean by "always uniquely arrange for $0\le a<1$? Can you please notify me in your answer, and not in comments?